# data source to HDFS

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I want some clarification on below points:

How HDFS gets it data?

Does it take data from some DB in chunks, if this is the case then it means we need a central DB.
or, does it take data directly from individual last end machines say for example in this case a shops system where all transaction is happening and then saves it in chunks?

I know how HDFS works (googled it a lot) but just confused about above said points.

appreciate any help...

Thanks,
Pankaj

Comment: @SuvP : What if my data is not stored on my local FS?

Comment: @SuvP : Please don't mind. I was just trying to make things clear.

Comment: It takes(it doesn't take it automatically) data from your **local system** (but not limited to your local system. You may have other sources from which you can direct data to HDFS, you can use `sqoop` etc to transport data to and from between databases and Hive). HDFS is a file system and it has is used for working on large files (GB,TB etc). You have to use `put` or `copyFromLocal` to put your data on HDFS if it is files on the local system

Comment: @Tariq Sure.Np. Thanks for pointing it out. Your answer is much clearer +1 for that

Answer (score 1):

Your question doesn't sound very clear to me. It depends on the client which is writing data into HDFS. HDFS doesn't pull data from anywhere by itself. It is the duty of your HDFS client to pull the data from a source and dump it into the HDFS. The source can be anything, from your backend database or to your frontend machines.

The client reads data from the source and caches it into a temporary local file. When this local file accumulates data worth over one HDFS block size, the client writes it to the DataNode with the help of NameNode.

So, it depends on from where you are reading the data. I'm sorry if this is not what you are looking for. Provide me some more details if that is the case and i'll update the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

you need to load data into hdfs on your own.
if you are using hive tables you can use following query :
hive> LOAD DATA [LOCAL] INPATH 'path to data file' INTO TABLE yourTableName